# Java Regular Expression to Replace all spaces surrounded by digits by a character

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace the spaces surrounded by digits or numbers by `-`.

so if my string is `I am Bob 12 12` This should get transformed to `I am Bob 12-12`.

Please suggest some possible answers using `Java`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\s(?=\\d)", "-");
```

This looks for a space (`\\s`) preceded by a digit (`(?<=\\d)`) and followed by a digit (`(?=\\d)`), and replaces that space with a dash.

If you want to replace groups of consecutive spaces, change `\\s` to `\\s+`.

Answer (score 0):

A non-regexp solution:

```
String in = "I am Bob 12 12";
int last = in.length()-1;
StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
resultBuilder.append(in.charAt(0));  // assumes, the String has at least one char

for (int i = 1; i < last-1; i++) {
  if (in.charAt(i) == ' ' && 
        Character.isDigit(in.charAt(i-1)) && 
        Character.isDigit(in.charAt(i+1))) {
     resultBuilder.append('-');
  } else {
     resultBuilder.append(in.charAt(i));
  }
}
resultBuilder.append(in.charAt(last));
// System.out.println(resultBuilder);
```

Comment: Why on earth would you want a "non-regex" solution that takes a dozen lines and isn't very readable, when a regex solution is perfectly suited, easy to read, and takes only one line? Boo!

Comment: ;) readability is worth a (separate) discussion. Personally, I hate looking at undocumented regexp and trying to find out, what the hell the author wanted to tell us and why it isn't working with my sample strings :D